# How do I write any positioning into a LESS variable?

Tags: css, less, positioning

So I was writing up some code when I decided I wanted to make a variable for margin and padding, along with some other positioning too. But when I try I get errors.

This is what my code looks like:

```
//Positioning
@margin_t: margin-top:0;
@margin_r: margin-right:0;
@margin_l: margin-left:0;
@margin_b: margin-bottom:0;

@padding_t: padding-top:0;
@padding_r: padding-right:0;
@padding_l: padding-left:0;
@padding:_b: padding-bottom:0;

@center: text-align: center;
@left: text-align: left;
@right: text-align: right;

@relative: position: relative;
@justify: position: justify;
```

Can anyone give me their two-cents? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### As of LESS 1.7

You can include property values in variables by [rulesets](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature), like so (note bracketing and following semicolon; p.s. `position: justify` [is not valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/position), I've changed it to `absolute`):

```
//Positioning
@margin_t: {margin-top:0;};
@margin_r: {margin-right:0;};
@margin_l: {margin-left:0;};
@margin_b: {margin-bottom:0;};

@padding_t: {padding-top:0;};
@padding_r: {padding-right:0;};
@padding_l: {padding-left:0;};
@padding:_b: {padding-bottom:0;};

@center: {text-align: center;};
@left: {text-align: left;};
@right: {text-align: right;};

@relative: {position: relative;};
@absolute: {position: absolute;};
```

A variable assigned ruleset is use much like a mixin (note the parentheses on the call), so:

```
.yourClass {
    @relative();
}
```

Produces:

```
.yourClass {
  position: relative;
}
```

The differences of a variable ruleset to a mixin are that you cannot pass parameters to a ruleset (directly anyway), but a ruleset can itself be passed as a parameter to a mixin. Also, variable rulesets will *overwrite* a previous definition (no matter properties defined), whereas mixins will *merge* property values. Rulesets work well for fixed values, like some of your items. They can be parametrized indirectly, something like so:

```
@margin_t: {margin-top: @tm;};

.yourClass {
    @tm: 0;
    @margin_t();
}
```

Varible rulesets actually work best for when one wants to *pass **to** a mixin a group of properties* or a single, unknown dynamic property. As an example of the latter, suppose you know you will want to set a single margin for an element, but depending on some context, you don't know which you want to set, so you want a single way to handle it. Then something like this can be done:

```
@margin_t: {margin-top: @value;};
@margin_r: {margin-right: @value};
@margin_l: {margin-left: @value;};
@margin_b: {margin-bottom: @value;};

.set-a-margin(@prop; @value: 0;) {
    @prop();
}

.yourClass {
    .set-a-margin(@margin_r; 10px);
}

.anotherClass {
    .set-a-margin(@margin_b; 5px);
}
```

Produces:

```
.yourClass {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.anotherClass {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Basically, variable assigned rulesets just offer another way LESS can be used to code the way you may want to code. They can offer some functionality like mixins, with certain limitations and advantages different from those as related to variables.

Comment: I suspect it could be less confusing to use "detached ruleset" or "unnamed ruleset" term when describing this particular feature (i.e. "assigning a ruleset to a variable"). *Just* `a ruleset` is more general Less/[CSS entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets), e.g. any mixin is actually a ruleset too thus things like "the differences of a ruleset to a mixin ..." sound a bit weird.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Hmmm. I see your point, though "unnamed ruleset" does not work, as it is named (by assignment to a variable), and "detached" also seems inappropriate, as it is attached to a variable. In LESS, there are 3 differences of these to a mixin: (1) does not accept parameters directly, (2) is itself passable as a parameter/assignable to a variable, (3) overwrites rather than merges on redefinition (as a variable). So perhaps the term should be "variable assigned ruleset" or simply "variable ruleset"?

Comment: Well the trick is that the `{...}` part *is* the unnamed ruleset. The name of the variable it is assigned to is still a name of the variable (and not a name of the ruleset) and the variable itself still remains just a plain variable (e.g. you can assign another value of any kind to it later). My "unnamed" and  lukeapage's ["detached"](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1859) came from: `.mixin(1, 2, 3, /* I don't know who I am here: */ {...});`. But sure, all this strict terminology is not that important, I guess any name except "just a ruleset" would fit.

Comment: Technically it is just plain old good CSS ruleset just without explicitly specified selector (i.e. "name") having all the standard functionality of the non-parametric ruleset. The only new feature is that variables can now accept such "value" and make it invokable as a mixin with `()`. />"overwrites rather than merges on redefinition" - this is the property of the variable the ruleset is assigned to (but the variable is not the ruleset itself even if we can't access one without another). (Btw., [curious example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9609992#file-dr-in-array-less) :)

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I see the "unnamed ruleset" in the parameter passing of your example. However, technically, without assignment (attachment) to an "alias" of some kind (a variable, parameter, or selector) LESS either does not compile or the ruleset ceases to "exist." So it can never by truly "detached" nor "unnamed" in the code, even if the "name" is only the internal parameter name of `.mixin` accessible only generically with the "group" through `@arguments` or individually as `extract(@arguments, 4)`. I can definitely see why the correct "term" for this is challenging to come up with :-).

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the whole style. you would do `@margin_t: 0;`

Then use it

`.myClass {
    margin-top: @margin_t;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, define your mixins like this:

```
.margin_t {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.margin_b (@value: 0) {
    margin-bottom: @value;
}
```

and then just use it!

```
body {
    .margin_t();
    .margin_b(15px);
}
```

Comment: And then whatever px-value I want to add I just put it inbetween the brackets?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show two possible usings - with parameters and without.